# how can I validate multiple xml files with xmllint

Tags: node.js, xmllint

I'm using **xmllint** to validate xml files in my nodejs project, but I have problems with validating multiple files

I need a script that check all xml files in the whole project, here is the script that am using in the package.json

```
"validate": "xmllint *.xml",
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
for xml in *.xml; do
    if xmllint --valid "$x" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$xml valid"
    else
        echo "$xml no valid"
   fi
```

done